# Not able to fetch the /a/@href element by using Importxml on Google spreadshet

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

Can somebody please help me out what would be the Xpath that works on this website http://tuscanwillowick.com/ to pull out all the external links.

this is what I use for other sites and it works well : "//a[contains(@href, '/') and not(contains(@href, '@'))]/@href").

I don't understand what this website has different.

Thanks.

Comment: Proved more details on what you want to do and some sample code

Answer (score 0):

The website uses `Javascript` to display the data. It won't work out of the box with `Google Sheets`. You can use `Selenium` to scrape this or similar tools.

If you really want to do this with GS, you can use [ImportfromWeb](https://nodatanobusiness.com/importfromweb/) addon(number of requests are limited in the free plan). You have to specify to use `jsrendering`.

The following XPath will select what you're looking for (all external links) :

```
//a[not(starts-with(@href,"http://tuscanwillowick.com/"))][contains(@href,"http")]/@href
```

Formula in C6 :

```
=IMPORTFROMWEB(C2;C3;B4:C4)
```

Output :

[image: IFW]